# how do you check if element is already in the list through comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, for-comprehension

How do you check whether an element is already in the list when I am doing it in comprehension?

For example say in following comprehension I want to restrict duplicate numbers Though I am not looking for unique number at all, I want to prevent via an if condition.

```
[x for x in [1,2,3,1,2,3]]
```

I am looking for something like

```
[x for x in [1,2,3,1,2,3] if not in self]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [set comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and [conversion to list](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). It would do what you want without any odd syntax.

```
ans = list({x for x in [1,2,3,1,2,3])})
```

Actaully that can be also be simplified to

```
ans = list(set([1,2,3,1,2,3]))
```

but I think the first one might be better in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the comprehension as you're creating it (as far as I know; someone please correct me if I'm wrong!), but in your case you can just use a `set`, which eliminates duplicates.

```
uniques = set([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
print(uniques) # >>> set([1, 2, 3])
```

If your list comprehension needs to be more complex, you can index the comprehension from the set, rather than the original list.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
print([x*x for x in set(mylist)]) # >>> [1, 4, 9]
```

If you really need direct access to the list during creation, you need to use an explicit loop rather than a comprehension.

Comment: Actually its just an simplified example to demonstrate! I am not looking for uniqueness in the real problem that I have :(

Comment: In at least some versions of CPython you can access a list comprehension while creating it (with implementation-dependent magic), but it's not a good idea to do so; better to use a set (if order isn't important) or a simple loop (if order is important).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
y = [x[n] for n in range(len(x)) if x.index(x[n]) == n]
```

?

I think at this point, it's probably more readable to simply write it using a for-loop rather than a comprehension.